# How to record/identify all viewed RecyclerView items in Android with databinding

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

My current Android application displays a list of items via a RecyclerView.

I have a requirement where all viewed items have to be accurately recorded for reimbursement purposes.

I've tried recording each item processed by `onBindViewHolder`, however this approach is not accurate as items seem to be bound before they are visible.

My application employs `databinding` to populate all my applications `Views`, I feel there must be an approach that accurately records only those items that are actually "viewed" in my `recyclerView` by my users as opposed to items that are "bound" to the list `viewHolder`.

I do not wish to charge users for items they haven't actually seen.

Is there a method I can employ that is 100% accurate?

Comment: `LayoutManager` have some helper method to get visible item position . You can try putting a scroll listener and ,try to get position from `LayoutManager`.

Comment: I've tried scroll listener and the LayoutManager helper methods, neither approach works for "Fast" scrolling, items appear to get "missed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to create a `HashMap/SparseArray` which keeps id of each view item in order to be able to persist them in db.

whenever your [onBindViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onbindviewholder) is called you can persist id something else which represent item itself in sqlite db.

but you should keep in mind that `onBindViewHolder` will be called whenever user starts scrolling so this `HashMap` will be updated first and you will not miss any view item.

Comment: This approach "seems" to record items that are "bound" but not viewed. e.g. the recyclerview binds items that are not currently visible to the user at "the Bottom Of The List" off screen